# Launch camera activity with alternate permissions

Tags: java, android

I'd like to launch the camera activity and have it dump subsequent pictures into my private app storage. Since the camera doesn't have write permission to that directory, it can't save any of its pictures there.

I could make my private app storage world writable, but that defeats the purpose of having it be private.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(new File(this.getBaseContext().getDir(PHOTOHUNT_DIRNAME, MODE_PRIVATE), "filename")));
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Something like the above would be idea. Obviously this doesn't work for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Put the byte array of the picture to the SharedPreferences ? I haven't tried this, but it just came up in my mind. Or if your previous activities have access to that storage somehow, finish the camera activity with the photos, that previously where kept in the memory (not good idea, yeah) and save them from where you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to launch the camera activity and have it dump subsequent pictures into my private app storage.

That is not possible, sorry. Either use the `Camera` object yourself, or have the activity write the photos to world-writable storage and then move them to your app-local file store yourself.